# What is the optimal length of the H1 and H2 for a good SEO?

Tags: seo, h1, word-count

I read a lot and understand that headings give my text lots of value for rannkings.  Is the length of the content in H1 and H2 is relevant? Are there indications about it?

Many people say that the maximum characters for H1 and H2 are 70. Do you agree?

Comment: See also: [Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google)   I'm not sure that headings are much different than the rest of your page.   Put the number of words in them that makes sense for your site and your content.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller for the very interesting link. Do you think that a title of 100/130 characters with a text of 300 words, both with good content, could be a good ratio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no optimal length, it depends on the content of your page, but usually, H2 tags are longer than H1 tags because that they describe the subheadings regarding H1 and it's better to use H1 to emphasize important text, for example

```
<h1>Optimal length of H1 and H2 for SEO</h1>
<h2>Why does it matter to know the optimal length for H1 and H2?</h2>
<h2>How different lengths of H1 and H2 affects SEO?</h2>
```

But it's always better to make H2 tags short and H1 tags shorter and to the point, don't stuff it with unnecessary words because that will [negatively affect your SEO](https://blog.alexa.com/keyword-stuffing/).
For example, if someone searches for `Foo`
, and there are 2 equally SEO websites, except for that 
one has the H1 as

```
<h1>Foo</h1>
```

the other one has the H1 as

```
<h1>Foo Bar Baz</h1>
```

Site number 1 will be first because 100% of keywords are Foo, but if it was Foo Bar Baz 33% will be to each keyword *(regarding the heading only)*.

Another length factor rule is the content of your website.
Having keywords in the header which are repeated several times in your content is a good practice.

```
<h1>Foo Bar</h1>
```

content:

```
<p>200 words of content is a good practice 
regarding foo bar because 200 words of content foo 
200 words of content bar</p>
```

The only thing that Google explicitly mentioned regarding headings length is to not use [Very long headings](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en).

Comment: Is tag title invalidated for a good SEO by unnecessary words, as h1 title?

Comment: Put your self as the customer, and think what he/she is going to type in the search console, put the most important words, don't overstuff it, and if you want extra help regarding that, there are a lot of tools you can use to measure your SEO, search 'Wordpress SEO' for an example and you will find a lot of good tools, or any other tool according to what type of CMS you use, so, for instance, these tools will show you what are the most powerful keywords according to the content that you typed in the page, what you should put in the title, what you should put in the body... etc

Comment: as for unnecessary words, if you use them, they will deviate your target audience, so for example if your title is 'Foo Bar Baz' and your page is about 'Foo Bar' only, and someone searches for 'Baz' and finds you, he is just gonna visit your page for few second then leave because it's misleading, and he is looking for 'Baz' not something else. and page visit duration is recorded if your site uses analytical tools that reports to ranking websites such as Alexa, which is bad if your visitors only stay for a short time then they immediately leave.