# SEO tools report that the keywords in modal dialogs are important for my website

Tags: seo, keywords, tools

I noticed most of the notable keywords from our website's landing page comes from our term and conditions which is a modal embedded after the closing body tag. I used `https://neilpatel.com/` to analyze our website.

I think that the modal contents are affecting my keyword count thus might affect my SEO score.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Neilpatel's sites for analysis are fake (it means those error/score are actually dumb, and search console is 100x better than that), put his own site on his tool, and it will show an error. Quicksporut is another example. They are marketing guys in my POV, not SEO experts (especially not for technical SEO). It will be great if you remove the link to his site, and use plain text :)

Comment: If we disregard the use of Neilpate site, would it still be bad for my SEO if our terms and conditions are contained in a modal?

Comment: I don't think it will cause any problem if you add your privacy policy or TOS links inside body tag or not. Google generally pass less rank to those pages. You can consider it as heading like h1, h2... h6. H1 is more important than H3, similarly privacy policy, terms and sidebar links are same as h5 and h6, those doesn't carry weight compare to paragraph links. Also let's say it pass some rank, but ultimately it will also link to your homepage, so rank will again distribute. For [word count check this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/106761/58259)