# Word Count isn't a ranking factor, is there any case study or proof?

Tags: seo, google, ranking

According to many information like [Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google) and https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1021690796691607552 word count isn't a ranking factor.

But I have never seen that 300-word article (even 500 words) is on the first page for at least 500 search volume(monthly) keyword.

Is there any case study or an example to prove that "Word Count isn't a ranking factor"?

Comment: [Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google) has many well-reasoned answers explaining why people think that word count is not a ranking factor.  How is this not a duplicate question?   There is almost never "proof" in the SEO world.  Google rarely says anything definitive and studies are hard to do.  Studies can only show correlation anyway.  What proof do you need?

Comment: What does a word count ranking factor mean, anyway?   There is certainly a correlation between some sufficient number of words and rankings as you point out.   However, a ranking factor implies that Google counts the words in a document and adjusts rankings specifically based on that number.    See the full comment discussion on the [one answer that says word count could be a ranking factor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106763/14543) on that question.

Comment: The tweet you reference is from [@JohnMueller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/711/john-mueller) who works at  Google with the Google Search team (and a user of this site) and that tweet basically states that word count is not a ranking factor (specifically, "Word count is not indicative of quality.") - I would have said that that is pretty conclusive! (In fact, that tweet should be referenced in an answer on the linked question - I can't see it mentioned currently.)

Comment: @MrWhite you can edit my answer to do that, I think there are still many grammatical errors lefts in my answer. Or you can add separate answer as well. Or may be some comments on that.